# Export database from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've managed to 'Restore' my database using the SQL Server Management Studio.

I now need to export that so I can import it into my websites empty database.

I've tried `Tasks/Generate Scripts` but I can't import the file it generates into my database on my site.

I get the following error message:

> *Could not find stored procedure 'xxx'*

I've also tried to `Export Data` but I don't appear to get a result at the end of the process. Possibly because I'm using the free version of the software?

Are there any other ways to export this data into a `.sql` file so I can import it?

I'm just moving a site from one server to another - it shouldn't be this difficult!

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: You can take a full database backup in MS SQL Management studio. Restore that backup to your empty database.

Comment: I've restored the DB from a .bak backup file (locally) - I need to export it and upload to the new server.

Comment: @dave : Login to this new server Remotely. Copy .bak file on the server and restore DB there.

Comment: Thanks but i only have access to the new server via a basic CP - its hosted at 123-Reg.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard. Available at:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5498

Use the generated .SQL file with these steps:

http://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Databases/Windows-MSSQL/how-do-i-import-export-a-mssql-database-793/

Comment: Thanks Dave, I downloaded the Software but I get an error when connecting to the DB. "This SQL Server Version (11.0) is not supported. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)" Possible because I;m using MS SQL Server Management Studio 2012?

Comment: In SQL 2012 the functionality has been included. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210545.aspx

Comment: Thanks - I can't access the DB remotely (123-Reg confirmed this) and when I import my DB that I exported via 'Tasks/Generate Scripts -> save scripts to a specific location' I get the error message as indicated above "Could not find stored procedure 'xxx'" - Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you make sure to set up the appropriate DB users on the remote DB first.  You also may have to fix the user mappings using EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Update_One', username, login  . See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259633(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Hi Dave - I have 7 users in the original DB, I dont have passwords for any of them, presumable I can't add users on the remote DB with them?

Comment: I've added a new user, assigned it a default DB and mapped it to the DB. I then exported the SQL to file, imported it to the new server and got the same error message!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've managed to resolve this but I have found that the SQL file saved from SSMS is in Unicode format and the 123-Reg website is expecting plain text. This is what's causing the "Could not find stored procedure..." error message.

Instead of saving the file, copy and paste the text from SSMS into Notepad, then save that. The file should then upload correctly into the remote database.